# Access reports saved in users personal folders

Tags: salesforce, report, salesforce-lightning

I have a requirement to replace a few of the deprecated fields with new fields and these deprecated fields are referred in reports which users are saved to their personal folders? is there any way to access them?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the profile permission "Manage All Private Reports and Dashboards"